# Why does the VS Code 1.84 color picker close after clicking any input in it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am learning CSS and trying to use the RGB color picker on VS Code however whenever I click to select, the color picker closes before I can click anything else.

Basically, I need to change one value and open it again to change another.

I've tried setting the code format in the bottom right corner to CSS and I have also tried installing a separate color picker extension, however, I would quite like to use the built in one if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably a case of the issue ticket [Color Picker closes prematurely after clicking anywhere in the picker. #197588](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/197588), which might be related to [Color picker immediately closes on click (not allowing cycling through presentations or changing opacity) when a presentation has additionalTextEdits #136965](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136965). I also don't remember VS Code behaving like this before, and I don't see any new settings about widget-closing behaviour, or the colour decoration behaviour. Add that with the high number of people also saying they are surprised by this in the issue ticket, and I'm convinced it's a bug.

The issue #197588 is purported to be fixed by pull request [fix: do not hide hover on model content change of editor #198100](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/198100), which is scheduled to be released in the stable channel of VS Code in the November 2023 release (1.85). You can probably also get it in VS Code Insiders if you can't wait.

The issue #136965 is purported to be fixed by pull request [Do not hide color picker on additional text edits #200232](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/200232). The fix will soon be available in VS Code Insiders, and will be released in the January 2024 stable release (end of January 2024).

Comment: Still not fixed as of March 2024. I'd also like to stop it jumping to RGB colors unless I specifically tell it to. Very poor UX.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean like this?

[Image of RGB colour picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yALrs.png)

Try to click it once, as if there is something wrong with your mouse, it may double click and cause it to close.

Also, you can directly input the values yourself, or you can check online for values.