# VScode color picker overlaps the values in a weird way when I Change the color while dealing with colors like color or background-color in CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I'm facing a strange problem in vscode when i hover on the color picker (in color or background-color) and change the rgb to hex or hsl it overlaps in a strange way, also the color picker disappears after choosing a color so that I need to hover it again?

[vscode color picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB0Sb.png)

```
/*border is an example the problem on everything that has color*/
border: 5px solid hwb(334 0% 0%), 100%, 50%);
border: 5px solid #a52b2b(0, 179, 255); /*Different shape*/
```

It was expected to change the color value from hsl to hwb (or any other change -hex to rgb-)but the value is overlapped also after picking a color the color picker disappears so that I need to hover it again.

Comment: what do you mean by "overlapped"?

Comment: the part of your question about the closing is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77429583/11107541

Comment: the part about the weird overlap could be related to... y'know, the fact that your brackets are unbalanced?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be an issue with the color picker extension or the theme you are using in Visual Studio Code. Here are a few things you can try to resolve the problem:

1. Check for extension conflicts:
   Disable other extensions related to color or themes to see if there is a conflict. Sometimes, multiple extensions handling similar features can cause unexpected behavior.
2. Update Extensions:
   Ensure that your Visual Studio code and all extensions are up-to-date. Updates may include bug fixes and improvements.
3. Switch themes:
   Try switching to a different theme in Visual Studio Code to see if the issue persists. Some themes may not be fully compatible with certain extensions.